# "Valuable Inventory: No content" for my angular 5 webiste from google adsense

Tags: angular, angular5, adsense

"Valuable Inventory: No content" for my angular 5 websites from Google Adsense even though I have content on my website, so how to get approval from Adsense for my angular 5 websites since I read that it is difficult to get approval for a SPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sites should have sufficient high-quality content to provide meaningful user experiences and allow us to serve relevant ads to users. From [AdSense Help](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/81904)

It matters what kind of content you have on your website. It is Google's policy to serve ads that are relevant to website visitors. Since Google crawler can't decipher images as well as text you would need a lot of TEXT content to get approved for AdSense. That's why AdSense is best for blogs and websites with a lot of text content.

However I believe Google also considers what topic your website covers as well as how much traffic your website receives. I know for a fact that it is possible to get approved for AdSense even if you don't have a lot of text content.